# Removing changes from a file - GitHub/Git

Tags: git, github

I have cloned a project `newProject` and created a branch `new_branch`.

I made a few changes to `new branch` but after reviewing everything, I have decided not to use those changes, I have checked out the master branch, but when I use git status it still shows the modified files.

I have gone back and deleted `new_branch` but the modified changes are still there.

How do I delete the modifications (not the files themselves)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

using `git reset --hard` will remove changes of tracked files.

using `git clean -df` will remove new added untracked files.

Comment: I did git reset and it says "Unstaged changes after reset:" with the list of modifications after it.  Do I need to stage them first?

Comment: @rbynrls I'm sorry, using `git reset --hard` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Execute the following command, which will remove all changes and newly created files

```
 git clean -df
```

Another option, if you wanted to save the changes for possible use later, but still remove them from the branch you could execute:

```
git stash
```

Then when you want to put these changes back in execute:

```
git stash apply
```

Comment: I tried 'git clean -df' and nothing happened, it is still there.

Comment: You shouldn't have been able to checkout master if there were unsaved changes in your branch.  Did you commit these changes?

Comment: I did not commit the changes.  I used git checkout master, and then git branch -d new_branch.  This deleted the new branch and took checked out master, but the modified files are still there when I use git status.

Comment: git clean -d Removes untracked directories in addition to untracked files.  I am looking to remove just the changes made to those files, not the files themselves.